# Handling state with multiple checkboxes in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-elements

I have a simple form with two checkboxes for someone to choose one or the other i.e `Yes` or `No` not both. Am using the `React-native-element` toolkit as shown below.

```
export default class CheckerForm extends React.Component {
     state = {
       checked: false,
      }
    handleYesCheck =() => {
       this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})
    }

    handleNoCheck =() => {
      this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})
    }

    render(){

   const { checked } = this.state
     return (
      <View>
       <CheckBox
       center
        title='Yes'
        checked={checked}
        onPress={this.handleYesCheck}
     />
     <CheckBox
      center
      title='No'
      checked={checked}
      onPress={this.handleNoCheck}
    />
   <View>
```

I want to capture and modify the state of the checkboxes but when I click one of the checkboxes I modify the state of the other i.e both will be checked and unchecked. How can I modify the states of the checkboxes independently such that when I click on `Yes`, `No` is unchecked and vice versa? Generally what is the best way to capture the state so that I can use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is have a array of checkboxes, and save in the state the index of the checked one.

```js
state = {
  checkedId: -1,
  checkboxes: [{
    id: "yes",
    title: "Yes"
  }, {
    id: "no",
    title: "No"
  }]
}

handleCheck = (checkedId) => {
  this.setState({
    checkedId
  })
}

render() {
    const {
      checkboxes,
      checkedId
    } = this.state
    return ( <
      View > {
        checkboxes.map(checkbox => ( <
            CheckBox center key = {
              checkbox.id
            }
            title = {
              checkbox.title
            }
            checked = {
              checkbox.id == checkedId
            }
            onPress = {
              () => this.handleCheck(checkbox.id)
            }
            />
          )
        } <
        View >
      )
    }
```

This way you can also handle more than two checkboxes and also know which one is checked by the index.

Comment: Its generally not a good idea to use the index to track a checked value. Try to make your code more explicit and directive

Comment: @JohnRuddell why it's not a good ideia? If you want to have more than 2 checkboxes, how would you do it then?

Comment: I would reference something unique. Something that says the active item selected is x. maybe it means you define an `id` in your object, and set the `id` as the selected item. your `checked` property would then be `checked={checkbox.id === selectedId}`. Just as an example, but its more directive and potentially less error prone :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell that is a nice observation, using some unique property is really better than the index

Comment: Yep! if you try to keep it explicit like that, when product wants you to let the user drag / drop to change the order of your checkboxes ( as a use case for instance ), you can just implement that functionality without having to change the way validation works. Because changing the order would introduce a bug of array index to checked value (could check something you didn't want to check because of the index to checked mapping)

Comment: Makes sense though am not sure how I can implement it in the above scenario.

Comment: @WasswaSamuel vencovsky gave you an answer that should solve what you want, is there something missing?

Comment: @JohnRudell Actually his answer is ok. I was just curious about how you solve it by using  a unique property.

Comment: How you would solve what? the re-ordering of elements where a user can change the order? or your particular issue? reordering is a more complicated thing, [**heres a codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/5vxlnjrw1n) where you can reorder the columns if you're interested in how that would work

Comment: @JohnRuddell I meant my particular issue i.e How you would keep track of the checkboxes using a unique property.

Comment: @WasswaSamuel if you reference this answer, vencovsky updated to include an example with a unique id.

Comment: @JohnRuddell Seen it. What @vencovsky missed was also including a key for checkboxes i.e `key={checkbox.id}` otherwise, it works perfectly

Comment: Ah sure, thats just because he's mapping over stuff. ill fix his answer :)